# How do we prove the rank-nullity theorem when the kernel is trivial?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Theorem**: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear function. Then: $dim(Ker(f)) + dim(Im(f)) = dim(V)$

In the proof of this theorem, they say:

V is finite dimensional, thus Ker(f) is finite dimensional. Take a basis {$ \overrightarrow{v_1}, \overrightarrow{v_2}, \dots,  \overrightarrow{v_n}$} of Ker(f), and expand to a base of V.

**My question**: What if Ker(f) = {$\overrightarrow{0}$}? Then we cannot expand this basis to a basis of V (as this basis is the empty set). I tried to make the proof work by trying to prove that the theorem becomes trivial then, this means: it's trivial that $dim(Im(f)) = dim(V)$, but this doesn't seem trivial to me. We know that f is injective, but can we use that?

Comment: The proof works just fine for the case $\mbox{Ker}(f)=0$. In this case, the basis of the kernel is $\varnothing$ which is extendible to a basis of $V$. Btw, there is an easier way to prove the theorem in this case. If Ker$(f)=0$ then $f$ is injective and it clearly surjects onto Im$(f)$ by the definition of Im$(f)$. Thus $f$ is an isomorphism from $V$ to $\mbox{Im}(f)$, so dim$(V)=$dim Im$(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the basis of $\ker f$ is $\emptyset$, then any basis of $V$ is an extension of it. If you have a basis of $V$ (say, $S$), then $\emptyset \subset S$ because $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set and thus $S$ is an extension of $\emptyset$.

Also, as you said, if $\dim(\ker f)=0$, then $f$ is injective. Also, $f$ is surjective with $\text{Im } f$ by the definition of image, so $f$ is bijective with $\text{Im } f$. This means it is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\text{Im } f$, so $\dim V=\dim \text{Im } f$.